# Sharepoint 2010 Break permission inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-2010, permissions, sharepoint-workflow, sequential-workflow

I need to create a workflow that would break permission inheritance in a sharepoint subsite.

I am building a sharepoint 2010 site that is highly modular and can expand based on clients needs. The project requirement is that the client must be able to expand the website and add subsites from templates with as little interaction as possible. To this end I have created a list and attached a workflow to this list that creates a new website based on the information supplied in the list fields. The workflow I am using is a solution I found online http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2011/02/create-site-action-sharepoint-designer.html

After the website is created I need to create security groups (another workflow I found online helps with this).

The problem is that the subsite must inherit security groups from the parent site and then I need to add new ones. In order to do this I need to break inheritance from the parent site and than I can create new groups. Currently my client has to do this manually - very bad thing. So I need create a workflow that would do just that.

The problem is that I am completely clueless as to how to go about doing this.

Ideally, I would like to create some sort of workflow action that would take a site url as input and then break permission. From what I've been able to find I need to use BreakRoleInheritance function to do that. but how do I create a workflow that takes input and how do i convert the string input into an actual site?

Like I said, I don't know anything about coding for sharepoint so please be as specific as possible.

Thank you very much.

P.S. maybe I am mistaken and i don't need to break inheritance to create additional security groups that would work only for a given subsite. If so, please tell me how to do this without breaking inheritance.

Comment: Couple questions to help with someone provide you with a better answer.
Do you know c# or vb.net?
Who owns the SharePoint farm?
I don't know of any way to accomplish what you are asking without writing some custom code, hopefully someone else may know how to.
Will the farm administrator let you deploy a custom solution?
Are sandbox solutions enabled?

Comment: This will require some custom code. There are a number of options for this: a workflow developed in visual studio, a custom action for a SharePoint Designer workflow, or a custom feature and feature stapler to activate the feature on site creation.